# Encoding Issues on Linux Server

Tags: java, linux, encoding, utf-8, aem

Java CQ5 Application is deployed on a Linux machine. It hits a servlet(again deployed on another Linux machine) which returns an UTF-8 encoded XML in the response.

The issue is even the XML is encoded in UTF-8 , it shows � for special characters like ë.

and when i deploy the same application locally on my Windows Machine and hit the same servlet it is working fine with no encoding issues.

i have checked the default encoding of linux server it is set to en_us.utf8. i tried changing the default encoding of linux to fr_FR.utf8 but it still did not worked.

Please help !

Comment: how about use command `dos2unit` to convert this file?

Comment: How do you know that it uses special characters? By which I mean: this may be a consequence of **how** you are viewing it.

Comment: Is the other servlet also CQ or any other application? Where exactly do you get the wrong encoding. In an editor or in CRX DE Lite?
If you post to a CQ servlet you need to have a paramter "_charset_=UTF-8"

Comment: @Thomas: other servlet is also running on cq5. I got this on the webpage which is making the use of XML sent as a response by the servlet.I have also checked it by adding the "_charset_=UTF-8" parameter while posting to servlet, i am still getting the same issue.